# How to get the size and the starting address of the stack per thread in posix C?

Tags: c, stack

How can I get the size and the starting address of the stack per thread in posix C? Or if there's no standard posix way to do this, at least in Linux with gcc.

Some programs such as the Boehm-gc should do this somehow, but I'm now quite confused reading their code. Can you give me some function names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clean" but non-portable way to do this is to use the `pthread_getattr_np` (Linux/glibc, etc.) or similar function to obtain an attributes object for the thread in question, then `pthread_attr_getstack` to obtain the stack base/size. There is no portable way to do this, however, and there's essentially nothing portable you could do with the results anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For the single-threaded case, just take the address of a local variable in the original and current frames.

Any address that lies between the current function's stack and main's stack must be in the stack.

Note that this does *not* apply to variables located directly. You may have to disable inlining for a handful of functions.